# Java Spring send back message to queue from consumer

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a service that sends message to rabbitmq and the consumer do some manipulation of the message and re-queue them.

I can successfully send to rabbitmq the initial message but the problem is i cannot resend to rabbitmq any consumed message if the message requires modifications.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    /**
     * The template
     */
    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;
    private final RabbitMQConfig config;

    public void send(String message) {
        try {
            amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("ex", "r", message);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my config i have setup:
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() { /* working code */ }

```
@Bean
public Queue myQueue() { return new Queue("my-queue"); 
// etc...

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter myListenerAdapter(MyListener listener) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "listener");
}

@Bean
MyListener myListener() {
    return new MyListener();
}
```

then...

```
public class MyListener {
    public void receiveMessage(String message) { 
        // ... some code
        // if message requires modification, then repush
        new Repush().push(message);
    }
}
```

I tried to create a new class with new  but the "myService" always null

```
@Component
public class Repush {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public void push(String message) {
        // myService is null at this point
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `new` for bean creation. Spring injects fields only in beans. Your `MyListener` is a bean. Just add `Repush` field with `@Autowired` annotation in this class.

```
public class MyListener {
    @Autowired
    private Repush repush;

    public void receiveMessage(String message) { 
        // ... some code
        // if message requires modification, then repush
        repush.push(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more than just field injection. The author needs to learn the whole concept of spring, bean, etc.

Comment: it's not compile-able BTW. Either remove the `final` keyword or add the constructor and if you add the constructor, Spring is smart enough to notice the dependency, so no need for `@Autowired` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `myService` as a bean in the application context as well as `Repush` as a bean you can then inject it into `MyListener` using @Autowired.

By creating `Repush` using new at point-in-time within the listener method, you are not getting a bean that is cognizant of the context you are in.

Comment: would it be better if I just call "MyService" in my "MyListener.receiveMessage()"?